# How to short an array in function? (Dynamic array, memory leaks)

Tags: c, memory

I have a dynamiclly allocated array, lets say:

```
double *values = malloc(sizeof(double)*3);
values[0] = 0.9988;
values[1] = 0.0540;
values[2] = 0.0100;
```

then, I have a function which should `shorten` my array, so I have only two last elements of the original array in new one. So, my result array should be:

```
values[1] = 0.0540;
values[2] = 0.0100;
```

As you see, I copied only 2 last values from the original array. Function should return a new size (old size - 1, I deleted the first element only). But with my code I get:

```
values[0] = 0.0000
values[1] = 0.0540
```

instead of:

```
values[1] = 0.0540;
values[2] = 0.0100;
```

Also, I have some memory leaks:

```
==5876== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5876== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5876== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5876== Command: ./Untitled3
==5876== 
--5876-- Valgrind options:
--5876--    --suppressions=/usr/lib/valgrind/debian-libc6-dbg.supp
--5876--    --tool=memcheck
--5876--    --track-origins=yes
--5876--    --leak-check=yes
--5876--    --show-reachable=yes
--5876--    -v
--5876--    --track-fds=yes
--5876-- Contents of /proc/version:
--5876--   Linux version 3.8.0-34-generic (buildd@roseapple) (gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) ) #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 18:00:10 UTC 2013
--5876-- Arch and hwcaps: AMD64, amd64-sse3-cx16-avx
--5876-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--5876-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib/valgrind
--5876-- Reading syms from /home/yak/test/Untitled3
--5876-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
--5876--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so ..
--5876--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 5d246d73 wanted cbf42dbe)
--5876--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so ..
--5876--   .. CRC is valid
--5876--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so ..
--5876--   .. CRC is valid
--5876-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
--5876--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux ..
--5876--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 8dadd6e3 wanted 096f8488)
--5876--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--5876--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--5876-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--5876-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib/valgrind/debian-libc6-dbg.supp
--5876-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp
==5876== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-5876-by-yak-on-???
==5876== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-5876-by-yak-on-???
==5876== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-5876-by-yak-on-???
==5876== 
==5876== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==5876== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==5876== or are doing some strange experiment):
==5876==   /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=5876 ...command...
==5876== 
==5876== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==5876==   /path/to/gdb ./Untitled3
==5876== and then give GDB the following command
==5876==   target remote | /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=5876
==5876== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==5876== 
--5876-- REDIR: 0x4018f40 (strlen) redirected to 0x3806c7e1 (???)
--5876-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--5876--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so ..
--5876--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 7ae7d82a wanted 34ea3d89)
--5876--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--5876-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
--5876--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so ..
--5876--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 272279e5 wanted bc83f658)
--5876--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--5876-- REDIR: 0x4018db0 (index) redirected to 0x4c2d440 (index)
--5876-- REDIR: 0x4018e30 (strcmp) redirected to 0x4c2e480 (strcmp)
--5876-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
--5876--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so ..
--5876--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 08d04634 wanted e58fe8a7)
--5876--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so ..
--5876--   .. CRC is valid
--5876--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so ..
--5876--   .. CRC is valid
--5876-- REDIR: 0x4ec1a30 (strcasecmp) redirected to 0x4a25710 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5876-- REDIR: 0x4ebddc0 (strnlen) redirected to 0x4a25710 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5876-- REDIR: 0x4ec3d00 (strncasecmp) redirected to 0x4a25710 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5876-- REDIR: 0x4ec0840 (memset) redirected to 0x4a25710 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5876-- REDIR: 0x4ec07f0 (memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5) redirected to 0x4a25710 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5876-- REDIR: 0x4ebf7b0 (__GI_strrchr) redirected to 0x4c2d260 (__GI_strrchr)
--5876-- REDIR: 0x4eb7520 (malloc) redirected to 0x4c2cd10 (malloc)
--5876-- REDIR: 0x4ec7bd0 (strchrnul) redirected to 0x4c2fea0 (strchrnul)
--5876-- REDIR: 0x4ebdce0 (__GI_strlen) redirected to 0x4c2d7c0 (__GI_strlen)
arr[0] = 0.9988
--5876-- REDIR: 0x4eb79b0 (free) redirected to 0x4c2ba00 (free)
arr[1] = 0.0540
arr[2] = 0.0100


==5876== Invalid read of size 8
==5876==    at 0x40063D: print_out_an_array_f (in /home/yak/test/Untitled3)
==5876==    by 0x40078C: main (in /home/yak/test/Untitled3)
==5876==  Address 0x51fd040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==5876==    at 0x4C2BA6C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5876==    by 0x4006E4: shortArray (in /home/yak/test/Untitled3)
==5876==    by 0x400778: main (in /home/yak/test/Untitled3)
==5876== 
arr[0] = 0.9988
arr[1] = 0.0540
==5876== 
==5876== FILE DESCRIPTORS: 3 open at exit.
==5876== Open file descriptor 2: /dev/pts/4
==5876==    <inherited from parent>
==5876== 
==5876== Open file descriptor 1: /dev/pts/4
==5876==    <inherited from parent>
==5876== 
==5876== Open file descriptor 0: /dev/pts/4
==5876==    <inherited from parent>
==5876== 
==5876== 
==5876== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5876==     in use at exit: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==5876==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 40 bytes allocated
==5876== 
==5876== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
==5876== Checked 78,504 bytes
==5876== 
==5876== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==5876==    at 0x4C2CD7B: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5876==    by 0x40068D: shortArray (in /home/yak/test/Untitled3)
==5876==    by 0x400778: main (in /home/yak/test/Untitled3)
==5876== 
==5876== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5876==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==5876==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5876==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5876==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5876==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5876== 
==5876== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
==5876== 
==5876== 2 errors in context 1 of 2:
==5876== Invalid read of size 8
==5876==    at 0x40063D: print_out_an_array_f (in /home/yak/test/Untitled3)
==5876==    by 0x40078C: main (in /home/yak/test/Untitled3)
==5876==  Address 0x51fd040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==5876==    at 0x4C2BA6C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5876==    by 0x4006E4: shortArray (in /home/yak/test/Untitled3)
==5876==    by 0x400778: main (in /home/yak/test/Untitled3)
==5876== 
--5876-- 
--5876-- used_suppression:      2 dl-hack3-cond-1
==5876== 
==5876== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

With this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_out_an_array_f(unsigned int n, double *arr)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("arr[%d] = %.4f\n", i, arr[i]);
}

int shortArray(int n, double *arr)
{
    int i;
    double *tmp = malloc(sizeof(double) * (n-1));
    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        tmp[i-1] = arr[i];
        //printf("\ntmp[%d] = %f", i-1, tmp[i-1]);
        //printf("\narr[%d] = %f \n", i-1, arr[i]);
    }

    free(arr);
    arr = tmp;

    return n-1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double *values = malloc(sizeof(double)*3);
    values[0] = 0.9988;
    values[1] = 0.0540;
    values[2] = 0.0100;

    print_out_an_array_f(3, values);

    printf("\n\n");

    int m = shortArray(3, values);

    print_out_an_array_f(m, values);

    //free(values);

    return 0;
}
```

But when I free the `value` array (before the `return 0;` in  main), I got other problem:

```
*** Error in `./Untitled3': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001d12010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80a46)[0x7f40adfa6a46]
./Untitled3[0x400799]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f40adf47ea5]
./Untitled3[0x400549]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 9440662                            /home/yak/test/Untitled3
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:08 9440662                            /home/yak/test/Untitled3
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:08 9440662                            /home/yak/test/Untitled3
01d12000-01d33000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f40add10000-7f40add24000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 16780936                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f40add24000-7f40adf24000 ---p 00014000 08:06 16780936                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f40adf24000-7f40adf25000 r--p 00014000 08:06 16780936                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f40adf25000-7f40adf26000 rw-p 00015000 08:06 16780936                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f40adf26000-7f40ae0e5000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 16779220                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f40ae0e5000-7f40ae2e4000 ---p 001bf000 08:06 16779220                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f40ae2e4000-7f40ae2e8000 r--p 001be000 08:06 16779220                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f40ae2e8000-7f40ae2ea000 rw-p 001c2000 08:06 16779220                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f40ae2ea000-7f40ae2ef000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f40ae2ef000-7f40ae312000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 16779153                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7f40ae4e9000-7f40ae4ec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f40ae50d000-7f40ae511000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f40ae511000-7f40ae512000 r--p 00022000 08:06 16779153                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7f40ae512000-7f40ae514000 rw-p 00023000 08:06 16779153                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7fff3fc3b000-7fff3fc5c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff3fdfe000-7fff3fe00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Comment: Two words: `memmove` and `realloc` — look them up. No need for `tmp` the way you're using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment `arr = tmp` changes only the local variable `arr`. It doesn't change the pointer in the caller. The errors you're seeing are stemming from `main()` continuing to use the old array pointer after it's been freed.

If you wanted to change a caller's `int` variable, you'd write a function that accepts `int *`. Here you want to change a caller's `double *`, so your function should take a `double **`.

```
int shortArray(int n, double **arr)
{
    int i;
    double *tmp = malloc(sizeof(double) * (n-1));
    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        tmp[i-1] = (*arr)[i];
        //printf("\ntmp[%d] = %f", i-1, tmp[i-1]);
        //printf("\narr[%d] = %f \n", i-1, arr[i]);
    }

    free(*arr);
    *arr = tmp;

    return n-1;
}
```

Then change the call to:

```
int m = shortArray(3, &values);
```

Comment: THANKS! But I got this error: `incompatible types when assigning to type ‘double’ from type ‘double *’` after changing this as you wrote :(

Comment: There is a bug at `shortArray()`, try `tmp[i-1] = (*arr)[i];`

Answer (score 1):

As John clearly stated, you are trying to modify a copy of the `arr` pointer, not the pointer itself.

If your function just shorten the first element and you are not concerned about freeing the memory of the discarded elements, you could play with pointers to avoid the array copy and the `alloc()/free()` calls:

```
int shortArray(int n, double **arr)
{
    (*arr)++;
    return n-1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double *values, *ptr;
    values = malloc(sizeof(double)*3);
    values[0] = 0.9988;
    values[1] = 0.0540;
    values[2] = 0.0100;
    ptr = values;

    print_out_an_array_f(3, ptr);

    printf("\n\n");

    int m = shortArray(3, &ptr);

    print_out_an_array_f(m, ptr);

    //free(values);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try shifting and re-allocating memory?